# "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

Tags: nginx, docker, configuration

I have an NGINX docker container with a an `nginx.conf` file i copy into `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. When i start the container/server, i get the following error:

```
2023/02/15 16:24:10 [emerg] 1#1: "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
```

I looked into it and there are a lot of posts about this error (granted, for different line numbers than "1"), but i don't understand what is wrong with this config. As far as i understand, the minimum "correct" nginx config should have this structure:

```
events {
    ...
}
http {
    ...
    server {
        ...
    }
}
```

with the `events` part being actually optinal too. **My config looks like this:**

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried multiple versions, removing something in every iteration, down to just this (with and without `events` part):

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
      try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```

and it still gives the exact same error. I rebuild the container and copy the config after every change, so it cannot be that. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the output of nginx -T

Comment: @Drifter104 I'm dumb, i DID make a mistake the last 2 hours rebuilding the docker image. It was a very subtle one, but basically i was rebuilding an image with the same name that was different than the one i was starting. Man, i had a feeling it is that but i rebuild it like 14 times to be sure. Classic. Sorry for wasting your time buddy!

Answer (score 0):

As i wrote in the comment, the error indeed was in me rebuilding the image wrong, resulting in the changes never showing up in the NGINX config. I somehow build an image with the exact same name than the one i was starting, but it was a different one by ID internally somehow.
TLDR; I'm dumb.